# How make localization in flutter without throw error?

Tags: localization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIoaP.png)

when i want make localization on my app to support multi-language ,throw this error
"^
lib/l10n/app_en.arb:1:1: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '{'.
{
^
Failed to compile application.
"
i try solve it but i can't ?

make space and search more to fix but not fix